# iCal library to iterate recurring events with specific instances

Tags: python, icalendar

I'm looking for a library (preferably Python, but the language doesn't matter much) that is able to iterate recurring iCal events and handles specific instances automatically.

The iCal file that I'm working with contains recurring events (for example: `RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20150614;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR`). These recurring events sometimes have specific instances: the summary might be changed for a single event, or one event is deleted. This result in `VEVENT`s in the iCal file with properties like `RECURRENCE-ID` and `EXDATE`.

Most iCal libraries that I've looked (python-icalendar, ical.js, php iCalCreator) at will help you with the parsing, but will simply return separate (and non-grouped) `VEVENT`s for all specific instances. This means you will have to match them to the relevant `RRULE` yourself and also determine how this influences the `RRULE`.

So, lets assume a recurring event that happens on Monday-Friday from 9:00-10:00. But with a specific instance on Friday (10:00-11:00) and a deleted instance on Wednesday. In this case I would like to iterate the events in a fashion like this:

```
[
  {start: '2015-06-15 09:00:00', end: '2015-06-15 10:00:00'},
  {start: '2015-06-16 09:00:00', end: '2015-06-16 10:00:00'},
  {start: '2015-06-18 09:00:00', end: '2015-06-18 10:00:00'},
  {start: '2015-06-19 10:00:00', end: '2015-06-19 11:00:00'},
]
```

Comment: Any luck? Have the same question

Comment: Unfortunately, no :(

Comment: @Intru, I edited my answer because there is a library now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python library [recurring-ical-events](https://pypi.org/project/recurring-ical-events/) unfolds events with repetition according the the RFC5455.

```sh
pip install recurring-ical-events
```

Example:

```py
import icalendar
import datetime
import recurring_ical_events
import urllib.request

start_date = (2019, 3, 5)
end_date =   (2019, 4, 1)
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/niccokunzmann/python-recurring-ical-events/master/test/calendars/recurring-events-changed-duration.ics"

ical_string = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
calendar = icalendar.Calendar.from_ical(ical_string)
events = recurring_ical_events.of(calendar).between(start_date, end_date)
for event in events:
    start = event["DTSTART"].dt
    duration = event["DTEND"].dt - event["DTSTART"].dt
    print("start {} duration {}".format(start, duration))
```

Output:

```
start 2019-03-18 04:00:00+01:00 duration 1:00:00
start 2019-03-20 04:00:00+01:00 duration 1:00:00
start 2019-03-19 04:00:00+01:00 duration 1:00:00
start 2019-03-07 02:00:00+01:00 duration 1:00:00
start 2019-03-08 01:00:00+01:00 duration 2:00:00
start 2019-03-09 03:00:00+01:00 duration 0:30:00
start 2019-03-10 duration 1 day, 0:00:00
```

---

Old Answer:

From the [answer of Sven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41479781/1320237),

[dateutil.rrule](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html) claims to handle the rules from ICalendar RFC 5545. If you have a look at the examples, it provides `datetime` objects.